# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps') using React and @google-maps-api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

Currently I'm trying to find a way to make markers and infoboxes for an array of points with longitude and latitude. The code runs fine for the first time but if I were to reload the page, the error 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')' comes up. Not sure what's causing this  problem.

Any tips or advice on this will be great

```
function Map() {
  const markers = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Chicago, Illinois",
      position: { lat: 41.881832, lng: -87.623177 }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Denver, Colorado",
      position: { lat: 39.739235, lng: -104.99025 }
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Los Angeles, California",
      position: { lat: 34.052235, lng: -118.243683 }
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "New York, New York",
      position: { lat: 40.712776, lng: -74.005974 }
    }
  ];

  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null);

  const handleActiveMarker = (marker) => {
    if (marker === activeMarker) {
      return;
    }
    setActiveMarker(marker);
  };

  const handleOnLoad = (map) => {
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    markers.forEach(({ position }) => bounds.extend(position));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  };

  return (
    <div>
        <GoogleMap onLoad={handleOnLoad} onClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)} mapContainerClassName="map-container">
          {markers.map(({id, name, position}) => (
            <MarkerF
            key={id} 
            position={position} 
            icon={"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png"} 
            onClick={() => handleActiveMarker(id)}
            >
              {activeMarker === id ? (
                <InfoWindowF onCloseClick={() => setActiveMarker(null)}>
                  <div>{name}</div>
                </InfoWindowF>
              ) : null}
            </MarkerF>
          ))}
        </GoogleMap>

    </div>

  );
}
```

I tried using {markers && markers.map(...)} but it still says that error

I'm expecting it to place markers with infoboxes following the data from markers

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue? It would really help in looking into what's wrong.

Comment: A working codesandbox link would be nice.

Comment: Hi there, my apologies but I was able to solve the problem, is there a way to flag that the problem is solved? Thanks

Comment: It would be good to give the answer in this question yourself explaining what really went wrong and what you did to fix it as it could be helpful for others also.

Comment: As for the solution to this problem. It was a problem with asynchronous situations. The idea was that React wasn't storing the data that was being called from a Flask API fast enough which caused it not to have any data in "maps" at all, therefore resulting in that error. A solution is to instead call the API using "useReducer" rather than "useState"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the solution to this problem. It was a problem with asynchronous situations. The idea was that React wasn't storing the data that was being called from a Flask API fast enough which caused it not to have any data in "maps" at all, therefore resulting in that error. A solution is to instead call the API using "useReducer" rather than "useState"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the API isn't fast enough so there's no data to send. Let try to add this prop: defaultCenter

```
<GoogleMap defaultCenter={defaultPosition} >
...
</GoogleMap>
```